# Encrypt folder on closing SSH, decrypt on starting SSH

Tags: encryption

I'm working on a remote machine, which I SSH to.

My goal is to have a folder which is encrypted when I close my SSH session, and decrypted when I open a new one.

I've tried using `ecryptfs`'s `ecryptfs-setup-private` putting the folders I want encrypted in the `~/Private` folder, but when I connected from another user's SSH, he could see the folder and its content.
I don't think I did anything wrong there, seems like it's not designed for SSH access.

The folders are quite large, and I wish to keep the time overhead as minimal as possible.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a description of what you've set up so far (configuration files, etc.)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, the only thing I did to try to achieve that, is setup up `ecryptfs-setup-private`, I've put the folder I wish to be encrypted when I'm not SSHing in `~/Private` and I checked from another user's SSH if it is visible - and indeed it was visible even though my user was not SSHed in

Comment: You need to look at running `ecryptfs-umount-private` when you logout, and then `ecryptfs-mount-private` when you login. You should also use `chmod og= ~/Private` to stop non-root users from seeing your directory.